# Setting a Promotion Rule in Magento

Tags: magento

want to set the rule on cart that

If cart total is greater than $200 then 1 fixed configurable product is free

is there way to set this using promotion rules in magento.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, when the fixed configurable is already in cart. You can create a cart rule where you set a condition for total being greater or equal 200. After that you choose 100% discount on the third tab and set a condition to describe the article which should get the discount, for example by it's sku.

Comment: can you please add steps for this I am not able to get this ?

Comment: you are not getting my question in cart there are simple products or else and the cart total is $300 now I want to simply provide 1 product which is configured and thats free if total greater than $200